# Using PayPal during CartThrob checkout

Tags: cartthrob, checkout, paypal-express-checkout

I am new to EE. Can someone guide me how to include paypal in payment type during checkout.
Currently we have visa,american express,Mastercard,discover

Comment: Using which e-commerce module? (They all have PayPal as a bundled payment method.)

Comment: @DerekHogue :I am using cartthrob and want paypal and stripe. How can i include? i should modify checkout template right?

Comment: What e-comerce module are you using for your cart? Store? CartThrob? BrilliantRetail? These all support PayPal _and_ Stripe, so I'm not clear on what your question actually is.

Comment: @DerekHogue I am using CartThrob and from the backend i have configured Paypal and stripe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PayPal is an *off-site* payment gateway, whereas Stripe is an *on-site* gateway, you'll likely want separate checkout forms, since the final action of each will differ (the Stripe checkout form tokenizes the card and sends it for payment, whereas the PayPal checkout form sends the user to PayPal).

So, on the previous screen before the payment step, give users the option (credit card or PayPal), then send them to the respective template based on that.

Then you just need to use the `gateway` parameter ([docs](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/checkout_form/index.html#gateway)) of the `checkout_form` tag so that each gets processed properly.

This tutorial may also help: [Allow the customer to select a gateway](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/allow_the_customer_to_select_a_gateway/index.html)